# Select query to return all rows where a column contains a domain name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that stores URLs and I would like to generate a select query to pull back all URLs containing particular domain name(s).

Example of URLs stored:
http://www.fox.com/files/apple.jpg, http://mail.redfox.com/help/index.aspx, http://apple.com/
etc.

I know what you're already thinking, just use LIKE.

The reason I can't is: `SELECT * WHERE Domains IS LIKE %fox.com%` it will return http://www.fox.com/files/apple.jpg along with http://mail.redfox.com/help/index.aspx (since they both contain fox.com).

I'm not all the savvy with SQL other than your basic queries, SQL Server can do some sort of regex magic I'm unfamiliar with?

Comment: then why dont you use: SELECT * WHERE Domains IS LIKE %www.fox.com%

Comment: I'd say that your first step is not understanding SQL or RegExp, it's codifying what you actually want to test / search for.  Unless you're asking us to give you an algorithm for that too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could test the domain name for both subdomains and *naked* domain:

```
WHERE Domains IS LIKE '%.fox.com/%' OR Domain IS LIKE '%/fox.com/%'
```

Sure, you can do it with a REGEX (`[\/\.]fox.com\/`), but simple SQL might be easier to remember/understand later on.